# Replace the default checkmark for UITableView with a custom image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'd like to replace the default checkmark image that is shown when a UITableViewCell's accessory is set to: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.

So I'd still like to write:

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
```

But I'd like my own image to be shown rather than the default.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to make a custom cell and add an imageView on right hand side of the cell. This imageView will then hold the image you want. On `didSelectRowAtRowAtIndexPath:` you can add the image and remove based on number of taps.

Comment: Thanks Parth, that's certainly one way but I was looking more to override the checkmark itself.  i.e. subclass the UITableViewCell and say if anybody asks you for a checkmark this is what I want you to provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method-1:**

I think you can use

Suppose you have a UIButton with checkmark image.

**On `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`**

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.frame = frame;
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

**checkButtonTapped:event: Method:**

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}
```

**accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: Method**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;

    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I have taken above code from this link:

[Implement a Custom Accessory View For UITableView in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)

**Method-2:**

Also there is a way to make it using custom tableView cell.

I think you have to make a custom cell and add an imageView on right hand side of the cell.

This imageView will then hold the image you want.

On didSelectRowAtRowAtIndexPath: you can add the image and remove based on number of taps.

Do let me know if you want more help.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 30):

```
myUITableViewCell.accessoryView = myImageView;
```

Then put your image in the UIImageView.

see

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewCell

Comment: That's what I was after.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Parth Bhatt

Answer (score 2):

Look this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
...
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray bjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

    [item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];

    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
    ...
}

    - (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event {
       NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
       CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
       if (indexPath != nil) {
          [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
       }
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

       [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

       UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
       UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;

       UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
       [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

[reference](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)

Comment: I think only posting a link is not useful. I think this answer would be useless if link goes down.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at work and then it seemed useful to at least post a link reference. Sorry for the brevity of my answer ;-P