# Increasing the height of the table view cells default accessory type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios5

Iam new to iphone development . I am using  UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark for my table view cell. I want to know whether it is possible to increase the height of this default accessory type programmatically or else using the custom image is the only option. I want to do this because I want a slightly bigger checkmark for my cell. Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I think here you might get the idea -

[click on this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208998/replace-the-default-checkmark-for-uitableview-with-a-custom-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the checkmark accessory type cannot change..... What you can do is add a `UIButton` or a `UIImageview` in the `UITableViewCell` and on its click perform an action.... Adding an image to the cell is relatively easy....

Comment: yea, adding an image to the cell is easy . Thanks for the fast reply .I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to implement custom accessoryType just go through following tutorial:
[link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

**cellForRowAtIndexPath** in this table view method using this code

```
UIButton *record_Btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[record_Btn setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 5, 70-20, 35)];
[record_Btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[record_Btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"record"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
record_Btn.tag = cell.tag;
[record_Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(pressRecordBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:record_Btn];
```