# How to create custom image check mark accessory for selected tableView rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I assign a custom image and for the select and deselect `.checkmark` tableView accessory?

Is it possible to also position this custom accessory on the left side of the tableView row and have constantly visible in the tableView?

When the tableView first loads the accessory is still shown just deselected essentially similar to the Apple Reminders app.

**Here is an example of what I am looking for:**

**Deselected:**

[image]

**Selected:**

[image]

**Currently, this is what I have:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: You need to create a custom TableView Cell for this.

Comment: Can you please show me how this can be done?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208998/replace-the-default-checkmark-for-uitableview-with-a-custom-image -- there, someone suggests using a `UITableCellView.accessoryView = myImageView` and switching the images, no subclassing required

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code. You need to create your own accessory view for my case I Just added one circle inside a custom view.After that you just need to make hidden true or false.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryView = CheckMarkView.init()
    cell.accessoryView?.isHidden = true
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryView?.isHidden = false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryView?.isHidden = true
}

}

class CheckMarkView: UIView {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame) // calls designated initializer
    let img = UIImage(named: "circle.png") //replace with your image name
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: img)
    self.addSubview(imageView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: code is not working, shows nothing

Comment: can you check does it called CheckMarkview for each cell?