# How to pin background image to right corner of the button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard

Swift 5, XCode 12.0
Could you help me please pin the image to the right side of the button, which is located in `UITableView` (storyboard)

I tried following code, but it doesn't help:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testnet: UIButton!
---------------
testnet.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark"), for: .normal)
testnet.configuration?.imagePlacement = .trailing
testnet.configuration?.background.imageContentMode = .right
testnet.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Here what I've got:

[image]

Here is constraints configuration:
[image]

I tried to see button configuration, print() below
[image]

Comment: Did you verify that the `configuration` property is non-nil?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add flexible offset to `UIButton` image. Usually such UI is [done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5959950/3585796) using cell accessory, for a custom image you [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209080/3585796) accessory view.

Comment: Have you given constraints to the button? if not please give leading and trailing constraints.

Comment: Finally done :) code below
`var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
configuration.background.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark")
configuration.title = "BSC TestNet"
configuration.background.imageContentMode = .right
testnet.configuration = configuration`